# How can I use WebRTC in a desktop application for voice chat?

Tags: c++, webrtc, desktop-application

I am trying to add voice chat between peers using my software - desktop application to desktop application over a network. My software is compatible with Windows and OSX. The difficulty is that there seems to be very little documentation on using the native API, and all the tutorials I've come across are out of date.

I started off by building the libraries and linking them in a new project, but as I mentioned, the tutorials I have found on the Internet are several years out of date, so I didn't get far with that.

So instead I built the native code, following these instructions https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/, and have successfully used peerconnection_client and -_server, which work great.

My problem now is that the peerconnection_client is more complicated than what I need, and I'm finding it difficult extracting the relevant parts (I want to remove the GUI, connect to a peer programmatically, and only transmit audio). And even if I do manage to strip down the peerconnection_client code, to just make voice calls through a terminal, it would still be lot of code to then embed into my program because it isn't linked to libraries, but raw code.

Has anyone else tried using WebRTC for native desktop applications in this way before? Is there any up to date documentation for this I can use? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To have best chance to get a valuable feedback, you should be more specific in your question. Do not expect the reader to go on another site to understand the problem. Please, see [ask] and [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

**Best solution is to use this project :** 
  [CEF project](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef-project/src)

You will get mac os, windows and linux implementation from one project.

You can always update your cef library's to stay on road.

You can also use Firefox variant :

[Firefox implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Gecko_Embedding_Basics)

**There is a lot of other ways like :**

*QT framework*.
  https://www.qt.io/

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on a couple Voice/Video/Screen over IP projects using native C++ API, and my advice is: don't do it unless you have tons of time on your hands. Native API/samples is very much abandonware - Google devs keep it in sync with Chrome, but you're on your own, you'll have to dig through WebRTC & Chrome issues and PRs when your code stops working after updating to a newer release branch.
The only documentation is the source code itself, there's plenty of comments, but it's still very hard to figure things out. And those things tend to change from one release to another

Comment: I agree that WebRTC probably isn't the way to go... Could you recommend an alternative solution, or is your advice to give up hope altogether?